# Test for Equality using Store instead of ID

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I was wondering if it is a good idea to check for equality using two stores in an if statement, since it appears to be working.
Normally I would simply compare it to an objects ID but in a lot of situations it would be nice to directly compare two stores.
I am a little worried tho, since I don't know why this is working, if its a good idea in general or if there might be problems doing this that I haven't simply encountered yet:

```svelte
<script>
    import {writable} from "svelte/store"; 
    const store1 = writable();
    const store2 = writable();
    
    const compareToStore1 = (current) => {
        if (current === store1) {
            console.log("Store is Equal")
        } else {
            console.log("Store is not Equal")
        }
    }
</script>

<button on:click={() => compareToStore1(store1)}>Compare Correct Store</button>
<button on:click={() => compareToStore1(store2)}>Compare Wrong Store</button>
```

Here is the repl: https://svelte.dev/repl/93d43b5236954cb7951a09bfd58243f4?version=3.38.2

Comment: why are you comparing 2 stores references i can't see the utility, usually people compare the value stored in the stores. not the stores themselves

Comment: I have an array of nodes, each one is a custom store containing the same properties:
`const node1 = customStore();`
`const node2 = customStore();`
`const nodes = [node1, node2];`
Say, I want to create another store tracking wich node is currently active.
I could simply store an ID in each node and use that or I could directly store a reference to the store:
`const activeNode = writable(node1);`
That way I could simply call `$activeNode` and would have access to store functions of the active node.

Comment: So, you create store of store lol, yeah it’s OK. I don’t see a problem. But I would probably use derive store to un-nest the thing.